# If statements in a foreach loop based on Woocommerce product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I was using the following code to set images for each attribute term and it worked just fine only if there was **just one term assigned to each product**:

```
function tutsplus_list_attributes( $product ) { 
global $product;
$style = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_style', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
$new = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_other', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );

echo '<div class="att">';

if ($style == 'Red Wine') {
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/red-wine-icon.png" alt="Red Wine" width="35" height="35"> Red';
}
if ($style == 'White Wine') {
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/white-wine-icon.png" alt="White Wine" width="35" height="35"> White';
}
if ($style == 'Rosé Wine') {
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/rose-wine-icon.png" alt="Rosé Wine" width="35" height="35"> Rosé';
}
if ($style == 'Sweet') {
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/sweet-wine-icon.png" alt="Sweet Wine" width="35" height="35"> Sweet';
}
if ($new == 'New Wines') {
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/new-wine-icon.png" alt="New Wine" width="35" height="35">';
}
echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'tutsplus_list_attributes', 0 );
```

But obviously, some products will require more than one term i.e. New, White Wine, Sweet.

I've tried adding a foreach loop to to make it work with multiple attribute terms but now it doesn't show anything:

```
function tutsplus_list_attributes( $product ) { 
global $product;
$style = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_style', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
$new = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_other', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );

echo '<div class="att">';

foreach ( $style as $s) {
    if ($style == 'Red Wine') {
        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/red-wine-icon.png" alt="Red Wine" width="35" height="35"> Red';
    }
    elseif ($style == 'White Wine') {
        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/white-wine-icon.png" alt="White Wine" width="35" height="35"> White';
    }
    elseif ($style == 'Rosé Wine') {
        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/rose-wine-icon.png" alt="Rosé Wine" width="35" height="35"> Rosé';
    }
    elseif ($style == 'Sweet') {
        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/sweet-wine-icon.png" alt="Sweet Wine" width="35" height="35"> Sweet';
    }
    elseif ($new == 'New Wines') {
        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/new-wine-icon.png" alt="New Wine" width="35" height="35">';
    }
}

echo '</div>';
}

 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'tutsplus_list_attributes', 0 );
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $style is array or what? If its array,  check attribute term with $s instead of $style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:**

Here is another new version… For me both of them work. Try this one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_list_attributes', 2 );
function custom_list_attributes( $product ) { 
    global $product;

    $styles = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_style', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $others = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_other', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $path = get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/';

    echo '<div class="att">';

    foreach( $styles as $style ){
        if ($style == 'Red Wine') {
            echo '<img src="' . $path .'red-wine-icon.png" alt="Red Wine" width="35" height="35"> Red';
        } 
        elseif ($style == 'White Wine') {
            echo '<img src="' . $path .'white-wine-icon.png" alt="White Wine" width="35" height="35"> White';
        }
        elseif ($style == 'Rosé Wine') {
            echo '<img src="' . $path .'rose-wine-icon.png" alt="Rosé Wine" width="35" height="35"> Rosé';
        }
        elseif ($style == 'Sweet') {
            echo '<img src="' . $path .'sweet-wine-icon.png" alt="Sweet Wine" width="35" height="35"> Sweet';
        }
    }
    foreach( $others as $other ){
        if ($other == 'New Wines') {
            echo '<img src="' . $path .'new-wine-icon.png" alt="New Wine" width="35" height="35">';
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Original answer: You should try the following (I have revisited and compacted your code):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_list_attributes', 2 );
function custom_list_attributes() {
    global $product;

    $colors_array = array( 'Red Wine', 'White Wine', 'Rosé Wine', 'Sweet' ); // Your colors in an array

    $pa_style_terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_style', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $pa_other_terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_other', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $path = get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/';

    echo '<div class="att">';

    if( count($pa_style_terms) > 0 ){
        foreach ( $pa_style_terms as $key => $style) {
            // Check if color match with the colors in the array
            if ( in_array( $style, ￼$colors_array ) ) {
                $color = $colors_array[$key]; // Get the color name
                $color_key = explode( ' ', $color ); // Split each word in color
                $ckey_name = reset( $color_key ); // Keep the first word in the color
                $ckey_slug = strtolower( $ckey_name ); // Make it lower case
                // Displaying each color in the loop
                echo '<img src="' . $path . $ckey_slug . '-wine-icon.png" alt="' . $color . '" width="35" height="35">' . $ckey_name;
            }
        }
    }
    if( count($pa_other_terms) > 0 ){
        if ( reset($pa_other_terms) == 'New Wines') {
            // Displaying
            echo '<img src="' . $path .'new-wine-icon.png" alt="' . reset($pa_other_terms) . '" width="35" height="35">';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*  **Tested and works.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that's not working - nothing is being displayed.

Comment: @MichelleBritton This time I have been able to reproduce your product attributes and product  settings and to test it… So I have updated the code and it works now. Please try it and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, we are definitely getting closer, the icons are now showing but unfortunately only the first icon in the array is being shown (Red) so if the style is White, Sweet or Rosé it will only shown Red, despite Red not being selected.

Comment: @MichelleBritton I have added a new code version… If it doesn't work for you, is that you have specific things in your installation that I am not able to reproduce and Ill give up.

Comment: I don't think there are specific things in the installation. Have you add the new code, as it seems to be exactly the same as the last revision? Thanks for your time on this.